# Make a .sh file run at startup

Tags: linux, ubuntu, startup

I'm runnning Ubuntu 14.10 for clarification

I saw a [thread](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/27050/how-to-start-an-application-on-a-different-workspace) recently that showed a script that runs at startup.

I made my own version:

```
#!/bin/bash
wmctrl -n 4

chromium-browser &
skype &
conky-manager &
clementine &
covergloobus &
steam &
sleep 15

wmctrl -r chromium-browser -t 0
wmctrl -r skype -t 1
wmctrl -r conky-manager -t 0
wmctrl -r clementine -t 0
wmctrl -r covergloobus -t 0
wmctrl -r steam -t 1

#focus on the covergloobus so can setup.
wmctrl -a covergloobus
```

Then I added this .sh file to the startup manager: [Imgur link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/medpu.png)

My question is how to get it to execute, as it seems to not :(

Comment: `chmod +x yourscript.sh`?

Comment: @AlexanderO'Mara God dame it too smart

Comment: @AlexanderO'Mara its launching them, but not putting them on the correct workspaces. Do you know what to change?

Comment: Maby this can solve your problem: http://askubuntu.com/questions/814/how-to-run-scripts-on-start-up

Comment: I think im just going to use the conpiz manager for this. It seems to work pretty well.